# get specific element of object in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm saving an object in local storage, and the I want to list all the items when I load the page again, but I don't know how to get the info from the object elements. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
var estudiantes = [];

function agregaArray(i) {
    estudiantes.push({
        "carnet": $("#carnet_" + i).text(),
        "apellidos": $("#apellidos_" + i).text(),
        "nombre": $("#nombre_" + i).text(),
        "e1": $("#examen1_" + i).val(),
        "e2": $("#examen2_" + i).val(),
        "e3": $("#examen3_" + i).val(),
        "prom": $("#promedio_" + i).text()
    });
}

function agregaLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("114270311_estudiantes", JSON.stringify(estudiantes));
}

 $("#list").click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        console.log(obj.carnet);
        console.log(obj.apellidos);
        console.log(obj.nombre);
    }
});
```

Those console.logs return an "undefined" and I want to get the specific info.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the key `114270311_estudiantes` to store the value in the local storage, which is an array.

So you need to parse the result of that key to get the array, then iterate over the array

```
$("#list").click(function() {
  var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('114270311_estudiantes'));
  arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.carnet);
    console.log(obj.apellidos);
    console.log(obj.nombre);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

it is possible using just javascript

here is an example to get user id from the array list

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).id
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code not able to find out how you are calling `agregaArray()` &
`agregaLocalStorage()`; function. You can do `localStorage.setItem..` inside `agregaArray` function and avoid a second function.

Also doing `localStorage.length` will return all the stored items which may not be your interest.Instead you need only item stored by this key `114270311_estudiantes`.

For demo I am hard coding the values for the json.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var estudiantes = [];

function agregaArray() {
    estudiantes.push({
        "carnet": "1",
        "apellidos":"2",
        "nombre":"3",
        "e1":"4",
        "e2":"5",
        "e3": "6",
        "prom":"6"
    });
}
function agregaLocalStorage() {
     localStorage.setItem("114270311_estudiantes",JSON.stringify( estudiantes));
}
agregaArray();
agregaLocalStorage();

 $("#list").click(function () {
  var m = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("114270311_estudiantes"));
   m.forEach(function(key){
     console.log(key.carnet);
     console.log(key.nombre);
     console.log(key.apellidos);
   })
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/q19xad1m/2/)